# не получается добавить слой c TILE

Tags: карты, яндекс-карты, tile

ранее была на сайте установлена карта Яндекс с дополнительным слоем поселка, после перехода перехода на API 2.1 карта перестала отображаться. Я пытался согласно документации внести изменения, моих способностей не хватает. Кто сможет помогите пожалуйста. Ниже указан код который работал на API 1.0 и файлы которые готовил под API 2.1, тайлы находятся в папке /karta/ в папках от 0 до 16
файл работающий ранее

```
<pre>
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/1.1/index.xml?key=a0354aea-e329-4ec8-9e66-e1e12051b1f9" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/1.1/index.xml?key=a0354aea-e329-4ec8-9e66-e1e12051b1f9" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var options = {
                    tileUrlTemplate: "./%z/tile-%x-%y.png",
                    controls: {
                        typeControl: false,
                        miniMap: false,
                        toolBar: false,
                        scaleLine: false
                    },
                    scrollZoomEnabled: true,
                    mapCenter: new YMaps.GeoPoint(54.7040188659075, 56.1944801920867),
                    backgroundMapType: YMaps.MapType.SATELLITE,
                    mapZoom: 16,
                    isTransparent: true,
                    smoothZooming: false,
                    layerKey: "my#layer",
                    mapType: {
                        name: "Курай Тау",
                        textColor: "#000000"
                    },
                    copyright: ""
                },
                map = new YMaps.Map(document.getElementById("YMapsID")),
                myData = new YMaps.TileDataSource(options.tileUrlTemplate, options.isTransparent, options.smoothZooming);

            myData.getTileUrl = function (tile, zoom) {
                return this.getTileUrlTemplate().replace(/%x/i, tile.x).replace(/%y/i, tile.y).replace(/%z/i, zoom);
            }

            var MyLayer = function () {
                return new YMaps.Layer(myData);
            }
            YMaps.Layers.add(options.layerKey, MyLayer);

            var mapLayers = options.backgroundMapType ? options.backgroundMapType.getLayers() : [],
                myMapType = new YMaps.MapType(YMaps.jQuery.merge(mapLayers, [ options.layerKey ]), options.mapType.name, { textColor: options.mapType.textColor });

            map.setCenter(options.mapCenter, options.mapZoom, myMapType);
            if (options.copyright) {
                map.addCopyright(options.copyright);
            }

            if (options.controls.typeControl) {
                map.addControl(new YMaps.TypeControl([ myMapType, YMaps.MapType.MAP, YMaps.MapType.SATELLITE, YMaps.MapType.HYBRID ], [1, 2, 3]));
            }
         
            if (options.controls.miniMap) {
                map.addControl(new YMaps.MiniMap());
            }
            if (options.controls.toolBar) {
                map.addControl(new YMaps.ToolBar());
            }
            if (options.controls.scaleLine) {
                map.addControl(new YMaps.ScaleLine());
            }
            if (options.scrollZoomEnabled) {
                map.enableScrollZoom();
            }
            map.addControl(new YMaps.Zoom());
        }
    </script>
</pre>
```

Для API 2.1 создал файл s24.js с следующим кодом, что там добавлять не могу найти даже из песочницы, там только вставка вместо слоя рисунка но без привязки к координатам.Ниже код моего файла.

```
<pre>
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [54.7040188659075, 56.1944801920867], // Russkiy Yurmash
        zoom: 15,
            // Также доступны наборы 'default' и 'largeMapDefaultSet'
            // Элементы управления в наборах подобраны оптимальным образом
            // для карт маленького, среднего и крупного размеров.
            controls: ['smallMapDefaultSet']
      var layer = new ymaps.Layer(TILES_PATH + '/karta/%z/tile-%x-%y.jpg', {
            // Если есть необходимость показать собственное изображение в местах неподгрузившихся тайлов,
            // раскомментируйте эту строчку и укажите ссылку на изображение.
            // notFoundTile: 'url'
        });
        });
    
    });
</pre>
```

Ниже прикрепляю скриншот расположения папок с слоем для карты [image]